How to increase the lifetime of generated reports in pentaho-server 9.*?
Good afternoon To generate reports, I use pentaho server version 9. I use the standard queue and task API (reserverid, create job, status)  After successful generation, the report is stored for no more than a day. How to increase this time?  I get the report status via ~/status
I tried to dig into the settings, looked for xml files and found nothing. Tried changing the report loading parameters
